# Ionic: due to the reloading of the page, the button disappears

Tags: ionic-framework

I need your help. I recently started teaching `Ionic`, later I ran into a small problem. I use a bottom tab template for the menu. The problem is that in the `ion-header` I have an `ion-back-button`. This button works fine, but unfortunately, when you reload the page in the browser, this button disappears. How to make sure that the knpoka does not disappear? Thank you

```
<ion-header *ngIf="fullBox">
 <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-title>Details №{{fullBox.id}}</ion-title>
   <ion-back-button slot="start" (click)="goBack()"></ion-back-button>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


goBack() {
  this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

Comment: because when you refresh your history is lost. You can hardcode that button.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Please, can you show me how to do it? Because i don't understand how to do it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of *ion-back-button* is based on the app's history. When you refresh as @NajamUsSaqib says your history is lost.
I can see you are giving some funcionality to *ion-back-button* with *(click)* attribute, but is not necesary for this component because that it's the main functionality of the button.
For your problem, you can replace the *ion-back-button* with a simple button and maintain the click method you are using. This should show always the button regardless of app's history.
Regards.